# Как добавить изображение в круг Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Есть круг на канвасе нужно в него добавить изображение как это сделать?

```
ctx.arc(90,190,80,0,Math.PI*2,true)
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
```

Comment: например, можно использовать маскирование, т.е. у вас будет прямоугольная картинка и наложенная на нее круглая маска, в результате у вас получится круглая картинка  - например https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_clip.asp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам поможет [CanvasRenderingContext2D.createPattern()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createPattern)

```js
let ctx = c.getContext('2d');
let img = new Image();
img.src = 'https://picsum.photos/150';
img.onload = () => {
  let pattern = ctx.createPattern(img, 'no-repeat');
  ctx.arc(75, 75, 74, 0, Math.PI*2);
  ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
  ctx.fill();
};
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```